# Installing php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64

Tags: centos, pear

I'm working on a 64 bit centos 5.5 (Final) server
When I try to install pear it gives a dependency error

php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 (base)

So I try "yum install php-common-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3" it says that this package is already installed

Package matching php-common-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do

I don't know what to do anymore
Can anyone give me a tip?

It's driving me crazy
when I try yum remove php-common-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 it gives me the following
Package(s) php-common-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 available, but not installed.
I don't understand what's wrong with yum

Answer (score 0):

Try removing PHP and Pear, then try this from scratch as if your OS was new. It may help. Pear's a pain sometimes...

```
# yum install php
# yum install php-pear
# pear channel-update pear.php.net
# pear upgrade-all
```

Good luck!!

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a good option since there are people who are using my server and doing what you say may break everything :(

Answer (score 0):

to refresh your system, you might try

`yum reinstall php-common; yum install php-devel`