# Install php-devel centos

Tags: linux

I try to install php-devel on my server and I get this error

```
# yum install php-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.mirror.transip.nl
* extras: centos.mirror.transip.nl
* updates: centos.mirror.transip.nl
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package php-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

What is the problem?

This is my version

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

PHP 5.3.16 (cli) (built: Sep 16 2012 06:57:51)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5\_5.3.x86\_64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723191/installing-php-devel-5-1-6-27-el5-5-3-x86-64)

Comment: The answers there are not helping me

Comment: Did you attempt to reinstall of php-common and also ensure you have ran an yum update

Comment: yes when I try to reinstall php-common I get-

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Reinstall Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.transip.nl
 * extras: centos.mirror.transip.nl
 * updates: centos.mirror.transip.nl
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
No Match for argument: php-common
Nothing to do

Answer (score 3):

i faced the same issue

add repo "remi" by these commands

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

and enable the remi repo by

```
sudo vim /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

by setting enabled=1

now try

```
yum install php-devel
```

Comment: I've done this and it states that the package is still not available.